# How can I display post on the same date that I select in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I could use some help with jquery and datepicker :)

I have form that colect value from input and store it in the base.
In that one input I have a datepicker. 
**My questions is: "How to show post in front page on that same date that is selected in datepicker?"**

I tried something like today date vs date that is selected but function newDate() doesn't gave the same format like the one that is in the base.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 well">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Unesite naslov:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="naslov" class="form-control" name="naslov">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Izaberite datum:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datum">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tekst">Unesite tekst:</label>
        <textarea id="tekst" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Pošalji</button>
</div>
```

Comment: "How to ..." is a statement, not a question :)

Comment: also please post javascript part comparing dates.....

Comment: i don't understand what you want, with base you mean database? this datepicker is an specific library? it's jquery-ui? what do you want to achive exactly.

Answer (score -1):

please see simple example:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
         $( function() {
           $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         $("input[name='something']").val(dateText);
         }
         });
         } );


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker">
      <input type="text" name="something" value="thevalue" />
   </body>
</html>
```